# login applozic android app without registration

Tags: authentication, applozic

Applozic creates a new user if the user doesn't exist If it is a new user, a new user account will get created else existing user will be logged in to the application.
But I want to make a activity for login  without registration.
how do if existing user will be logged in to the application else it is a new user , Error message showing the user does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Call https://www.applozic.com/docs/platform-api-chat.html#user-details before the register process, if the "createdAtTime" comes null means user doesn't exist.